# How can I connect a P8 to a P4 motherboard?

Tags: connection, compatibility, motherboard

I have an older motherboard and I would like to connect a newer power supply to it. The motherboard has a P4 input, while the power supply has a P8 connector only (it is actually a 6 pin + 2 pin configuration). I tried to connect the power supply anyway, but the PC will not start.

Is it necessary to convert the P8 to P4 or it should also work like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 6+2 connector is for PCIe, not the ATX+4 (aka P4, or ATX12V) or ATX+8 (aka ATX+EPS, or EPS12V). They're wired differently and if you get the system to power on it's likely to fry something.

The ESP12V connectors should be two separate 4-Pin connectors, commonly they connect together themselves to appear as a single 8-Pin connector.

Comment: Thank you very much @Chris. Indeed I used the wrong cable. Your answer was precise and very helpful.